# Google Analytics with user hosted URLs

Tags: google-analytics

Is it possible to use Google Analytics on web pages served by a server hosted on the user's side? If so, what should be the "Website URL" when setting up the GA account?

An example is a WiFi router web service -- what if, let's say, DD-WRT wants to place a GA beacon on their router web interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Analytics can be used with any server or device that can send an http request via the measurement protocol.

If you are specifically talking about the javascript tracker, that can run on any javascript enabled device that can a) download the analytics.js library, b) has access to the public internet (so it make calls to the google analytics server) and c) can either set a cookie, or is configured to take a serverside generated clientid (to aggregate pageviews into sessions and sessions into visits for recurring users).

For data collection it does not matter what you put in the url field (else cross domain tracking would be impossible) - the value will be added to your referral exclusion list when you create the account, it will be used as a base for the in-page report (so you won't be able to use that) as as base when you open a page from within the content report. But you can use any valid website url regardless.